# Wrap property with dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

I interested in useful user control *Monitor* from the external library in my MVVM style project. 
All looks fine...but this control has simple (not a dependency)read only property (`IList<ILogSource>`), which I need to fill.
After thinking a little I decided to wrap this *Monitor* control with other control *MonitorWrap*:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Prj.CustomControls.MonitorWrap"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:UsefulControll;assembly=UsefulControll">

    <uc:Monitor x:Name="Monitor" />
</UserControl>
```

and at code behind i create dependency property:

```
public partial class MonitorWrap : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MonitorWrap"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MonitorWrap()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //correct ViewModel sets to DataContext
            };
        }

        public IList<ILogSource> LogSources
        {
            get { return (IList<ILogSource>)GetValue(LogSourcesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LogSourcesProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LogSourcesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LogSources", typeof(IList<ILogSource>), typeof(MonitorWrap), new PropertyMetadata(null,ChangeCallback));

        private static void ChangeCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var logControlPanelView = d as MonitorWrap;

            //add elements from LogSources to readonly collection property.
        }
    }
```

next step at parent xml:

```
<customControls:MonitorWrap LogSources="{Binding Sources}"/>
```

I expect that I'll fill collection at Change Callback method but it doesn't work.

So questions:

1. am I going the right way to fill read-only collection?
2. what's wrong? why `ChangeCallback` method won't  work.

P.s.
i'm using MVVM framework and `DataContext` sets correct(lambda expression in `MonitorWrap` constructor works fine).

ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and code

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(AdvancedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
            if (e.PropertyName == "Sources")
            {
                //works fine on property changed
            }
        }
```

works fine too.

Comment: So your expectation is that when you add items to the Sources view model property, ChangeCallback should be called?

Comment: Do you add items or push completely new collection every time?

Comment: No. i'm expect to see call of `ChangeCallback` when`LogSources` changes it's value from `null`(by default) to `typeof(Sources)` collection.

Comment: Also do you anyhow modify data before assigning it? Otherwise there is an easier solution to what you are doing.

Comment: @Karolis i expect to catch first push of `Sources` property to `LogSources` dependency property

Comment: @risty Ok, when you run the application look into output window and check whether it contains any errors. If so, please post them. Especially those that are anyhow related to LogSources.

Comment: @Karolis, no errors at output window. only _Symbols loaded_ messages. may be cause is that  `OnPropertyChanged` in view model rised before `MonitorWrap` creation and it's `DataContext` sets?

Comment: @risty Can you share source of it? Since from what is posted I cannot see the issue.

Comment: What is `OnPropertyChanged`, where is it defined? And please share viewmodel property `Sources` and how you set it. I want to know if its type is assignable to `IList<ILogSource>`

Comment: @EdPlunkett, tnx!  dependency property in user control has `typeof(IList<ILogSource>)`. property `Sources` in ViewModel has `typeof(ObservableCollection<ILogSource_inherited_Class>)`  and seems Binding system cant cast one to other. if i change user control dependency property to `typeof(IList<ILogSource_inherited_Class>)` all works fine. how can i make it work without type change ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IList<ILogSource>` looks suspiciously to me like you might be asking more of C#'s support for covariance than you're going to get.

The type of the viewmodel property must be assignable to `IList<ILogSource>`, and the rules for that are fairly strict.

Fundamentally, `ObservableCollection<ILogSource>` is `IList<ILogSource>` but it is not `IList<ILogSource_inherited_Class>`. It's not just the binding that can't do that. You can copy items from one to the other, but you can't cast. All you want to do is copy, but the typesystem doesn't know that -- it just sees you trying to do the assignment.

What should work is making the dependency property of type `IEnumerable<ILogSource>` ([see fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdWMYW)). All you need to do is copy the items out of it, so that's sufficient. Don't tell the compiler you need everything `IList<ILogSource>` can do, if all you need is `IEnumerable<ILogSource>`.